# How to use aggregate $facet query with mongo golang driver

Tags: mongodb, go

1. how can i translate the following query to pipeline with mongo golang driver

```
db.transFront.aggregate([
{
        $facet: {
            query1: [ { $match: { appName:"app-38" }}, { $count: "count" }],
            query2: [ { $match: { appName:"app-43" }}, { $count: "count" } ],
            query3: [ { $match: { appName:"app--1" }}, { $count: "count" } ],
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run **$facet in the go lang MongoDB driver**, use below code, just replace your connection string and DB name

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "time"
    "fmt"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

func main() {
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb_connect_string"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)

    database := client.Database("testdb")
    transFront := database.Collection("transFront")



    query1 := bson.A{bson.D{{"$match", bson.D{{"appName", "app-38"}}}}, bson.D{{"$count", "count"}}}
    query2 := bson.A{bson.D{{"$match", bson.D{{"appName", "app-43"}}}}, bson.D{{"$count", "count"}}}
    query3 := bson.A{bson.D{{"$match", bson.D{{"appName", "app--1"}}}}, bson.D{{"$count", "count"}}}

    facetStage := bson.D{{"$facet", bson.D{{"query1", query1}, {"query2", query2}, {"query3", query3}}}}

    showInfoCursor, err := transFront.Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{facetStage})
    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }
    var showsWithInfo []bson.M
    if err = showInfoCursor.All(ctx, &showsWithInfo); err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(showsWithInfo)
}
```

Comment: Happy to help :)